# Google Search Console Crawl Anomaly in Joomla 3.x

Tags: joomla-3.6, .htaccess-configuration, search, google

**Check the URL** - no errors 
https://www.dach-spengler.eu/sitemap.xml
https://www.dach-spengler.eu/robots.txt

In the google search console, I got the error:

> Crawl-Anomaly

**Submitted Sitemaps**

- Status Successful!
- Found URLs: 515
- Sitemap was processed without error
- View index coverage (Link disabled)

**Coverage**

- Excluded: 1 (Crawl anomaly)
- Examples:

  - URL: https://www.dach-spengler.eu/
  - Last crawled: 5 Jun 2019
- Test Robots.txt blocking:

  - Latest version seen on 12/06/2019, 21:40 OK (200)

**Robots.txt**

```
Sitemap: https://www.dach-spengler.eu/sitemap.xml
User-agent: *
Disallow: /administrator/
Disallow: /bin/
Disallow: /cache/
Disallow: /cli/
Disallow: /components/
Disallow: /component/
Disallow: /includes/
Disallow: /installation/
Disallow: /language/
Disallow: /layouts/
Disallow: /libraries/
Disallow: /logs/
Disallow: /media/
Disallow: /modules/
Disallow: /plugins/
Disallow: /templates/
Disallow: /tmp/
User-agent: AimySitemapCrawler
Disallow: /images/sampledata/
Disallow: *?tmpl=component&print=1*
```

**Inspect URL**

Retrieving data from Google Index…

Result:

> Coverage – Indexed, though blocked by robots.txt

**Discovery**

- Sitemaps: N/A
- Referring page: None detected

URL might be known from other sources that are currently not reported

**Crawl**

- Last crawl: 4 Jun 2019
- Crawled as: Googlebot desktop
- **Crawl allowed?: No: blocked by robots.txt**
- **Page fetch: Failed: Blocked by robots.txt**

**Indexing**

- Indexing allowed?: Yes User-declared
- canonical N/A
- Google-selected: canonical: Inspected URL

**Webseite**

- CMS Joomla 3.9.6
- Akeeba Admin Tools Professional 5.3.2
- Template: yoo_micasa
- Server: managed server, 7.2 php, allow_url_include

**Actual result**

> Error: Crawl-Anomaly

Comment: I just watched https://youtu.be/EUAMLEYAuno to learn more about the error that you received.  Basically, the error indicates that a url that Google visited returned a 4## or 5## error code (the page didn't load properly). The video talks about how to dig into the report and identify the flawed url then potentially drill down into that page's resources via the browser's developer tools.  We are going to need more specific details to help you to resolve the error.  Please update your question when you can.

Comment: thanks! I tried to describe something in more detail. I watched the video, but did not help me.

Comment: So Google is complaining because it can crawl to links that it has found.  Simple as that, right?  Seems like one of those "can't have your cake and eat it too" situations.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand the solution.

Comment: Stop Disallowing the Google bot from crawling if you are bothered by its inability to crawl your site.

Comment: you mean: Allow: /administrator/, /bin/, /cache/, /cli/, /components/ …?

Comment: This looks like a meaningful document: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062596?hl=en

Comment: thanks a lot! i will edit the robots.txt, excluding: Disallow: /administrator/
Disallow: /bin/
Disallow: /cache/
Disallow: /cli/
Disallow: /components/
Disallow: /includes/
Disallow: /installation/
Disallow: /language/
Disallow: /layouts/
Disallow: /libraries/
Disallow: /logs/
Disallow: /modules/
Disallow: /plugins/
Disallow: /tmp/